# Jquery: If an element exists, get it

Tags: jquery

To check if an element (for example a DIV) exists, I use this:

```
if($('div#someId').length != 0)
{
   // make stuff
}
```

Now, I need THAT element in my functions, but I don't know how I can refer to it.

For example (I know it's a stupid example, but it serve only to explain):

```
if($('div#chart-google').length != 0)
{
    var target = $(this).attr('id');
    google.drawChart(target,data,options);
}
```

So, how I can refer to it in my scripts?

Comment: Note you can safely access jQuery methods on an empty jQuery collection (the selector did not match any element): `$("#doesnotexist").attr("id")` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place it before the if statement into a variable

```
var elem = $('div#someId');

if(elem.length != 0)
{
   // make stuff
   var target = elem.attr('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` method to '*iterate*' through the one element -- ID selectors return only one element. And your selector does not have to include `div` in it, ID selectors are unique enough by themselves.

```
$('#chart-google').each(function() {
    google.drawChart( this.id, data, options );
});
```

If the element exists the line `google.drawChart( .. )` is executed; it is ignored if the element does not exist.